# how to aproximate shapes height and width for image detection using opencv and python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, omr

i was following a tutorial about shapes detection using opencv ,numpy and python ,and  it was this function i know the reason from it but i do not know how to modify it so i can use it as i want the total bubble's number are 320 but the function detect 303 only i tried to modify this line but the max i get is 303  (len(approx) > 8 and w / h <= 1.1 and w / h >= 0.8)
i want someone to explain to me this function  please

this is the code

```
    def getOvalContours(self, adaptiveFrame):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(adaptiveFrame, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    ovalContours = []

    for contour in contours:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0, True)
        ret = 0
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)


        # eliminating not ovals by approx lenght
        if (len(approx) > 8 and w / h <= 1.1 and w / h >= 0.8):

            mask = np.zeros(adaptiveFrame.shape, dtype="uint8")
            cv2.drawContours(mask, [contour], -1, 255, -1)

            ret = cv2.matchShapes(mask, contour, 1, 0.0)

            if (ret < 1):
                ovalContours.append(contour)
                self.bubbleWidthAvr += w
                self.bubbleHeightAvr += h
    self.bubbleWidthAvr = self.bubbleWidthAvr / len(ovalContours)
    self.bubbleHeightAvr = self.bubbleHeightAvr / len(ovalContours)


    return ovalContours
```

this is the image
[image]

Comment: you could try a different more general approach rather than sticking to the current one. The function `cv2.approxPolyDP` when used differently can get you what you want.

Comment: shape matching is likely not accurate enough at that size circle or your threshold is not clean.  Perhaps you should show your images and how you preprocessed before the code snippet that you show.

Comment: Have you tried using HoughCircles?

Comment: Your approxPolyDP and your subsequent test may be throwing some out. I suggest using HoughCircles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that using Hough Circles in Python/OpenCV.

Input

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('multichoice_test.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# get Hough circles
min_dist = 30
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=150, param2=20, minRadius=10, maxRadius=15)
print("circles:", circles)
print("")

# draw circles
img_circle = img.copy()
count = 0
for circle in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
    # corresponding to the center of the circle
    (x,y,r) = circle
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    r = int(r)
    cv2.circle(img_circle, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    count = count + 1

# print number of circles
print("number of circles:", count)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('multichoice_test_circles.jpg', img_circle)

# show images
cv2.imshow('circles', img_circle)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

```
number of circles: 320
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet tries to detect small circles by using the heuristic rule. You can tune the value a bit to get the number you want.
And you should look in the other methods for circle detection as well (for example [Circle Hough Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html))

Comment: An explanation is asked. This answer attempts to give one.