# Differentiating between circle and letter/number contours in OpenCV python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, omr

Using the method outlined in this website to isolate the circular contours: https://www.authentise.com/post/detecting-circular-shapes-using-contours, I was able to achieve the following contours outlined in blue in the photo. However, the method is not able to differentiate perfectly between the letters/numbers and circular shapes. Does anybody know of a foolproof solution?

[image]

This is my code snippet

```
cnts, hiearchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

contour_list = []
for contour in cnts:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.01*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if ((len(approx) > 8) & (len(approx) < 23) & (area > 30) ):
        contour_list.append(contour)
mcq = cv2.drawContours(paper, contour_list,  -1, (255,0,0), 1)

cv2.imshow("Image",thresh)
cv2.imshow("mcq",mcq)
```

Original images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxBU5.jpg

Comment: Use HoughCircles to find the circles. You don't need contours. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72491218/how-to-aproximate-shapes-height-and-width-for-image-detection-using-opencv-and-p/72624597#72624597

Comment: Compare minEnclosingCircle circle area with the contourArea. If they are very similar, the contour has very likely a circle shape

Comment: @fmw42 the reason I have avoided that is because although not specified you can guess I am analyzing responses on an multiple choice answer sheet, and often times the filled in response goes outside the lines of the circle, which according to pyimagesearch is not handled easily

Comment: If all circles you want have same size on your image, fit the circle to these contours to obtain the circle radius you want (e.g. as median of them).
When it succeeded, your work will become to find the circles with specific size(radius).

Comment: OMR is usually done by locating fiducials (triangles work well) in the corners of the entire sheet, aligning the sheet, and then blindly sampling where the circles are supposed to be. that's robust. feature matching for the alignment also works, depending on the form. -- everyone trying to find circles isn't gonna get much done, honestly. it's a case of bad tutorials. they aren't teaching you OMR, they are teaching you how to use a specific OpenCV API, and after they're done, they look at their junk and think, "this looks like an answer sheet!" and sell their bad tutorial as OMR

Comment: also, as you can see, your "scan" (photo) shows uneven lighting, likely due to the sheet being warped. you need to get that under control too. simple thresholding will not work as long as that isn't fixed. I'd suggest a median, best for estimating background (blank sheet).

Comment: @Joshua Yang. Can you post original image?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Can you shows me what it is meant by median? This was my first day with opencv and I am a beginner to this. By the way, here are the pictures I used for this https://imgur.com/a/Cdqvrw9

Comment: @toyotaSupra Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/Cdqvrw9 . If you have any additional comments to help me, please let me know; I can tell you also have attempted to use opencv for circle detection. Thanks

Comment: "median" meaning a median blur, with enough radius/iterations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcbEd.jpg this is `img / medianBlur(img)` (with suitable radius) it is a much better basis for thresholding or point/area sampling of the circles for infill

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Ok thanks. My last question is what you mean in your previous comment about "feature matching for alignment". So by that do you mean that if you have the format of a form you can match that with a picture of the student-filled form to determine where are the circles?

Comment: @JoshuaYang were you able to solve this?

Comment: @JeruLuke Pretty much yes, I sorted them in the end just by simple length, width, and area, although contourArea was the most reliable. Basically I filtered out all the random blobs or lines leaving only the question numbers or bubbles, then sorted and took the largest 208 (52*4) areas leaving only the bubbles. You can also make the 208 value larger to allow more leeway and add length,width as a factor too. Finally a major problem was that I used a webcam to take these photos, making the resolution bad quality. When I used phone photos, the results were much more consistent and reliable